# @Autowire repository works for Application yet fails in JUnitTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a weird issue of `@Autowire` failing as the following:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'EventTargetRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventTargetRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'EventTargetRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Funnily enough, this happens only on my test which uses the exactly same `@Configuration`.

`@Service` beans autowire perfectly in the actual application.
`@Repository` beans autowire perfectly in the actual application.
`@Service` beans autowire perfectly(??) in the JUnit Test.
`@Repository` beans **fail to autowire** in the JUnit Test.

Code is as follows(package structure omitted):

## Test(which fails)

```java
import CoreConfig
import EventTarget
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner


@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [CoreConfig::class])
class EventTargetRepositoryTest {
    private val LOGGER: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventTargetRepositoryTest::class.java)

    @Autowired //not autowiring for some reason. needs fixing.
    private lateinit var eventTargetRepository: EventTargetRepository

    @Test
    fun selectOne() {
        var eventTarget = EventTarget()
        eventTarget.id = 1
        eventTargetRepository.selectOne(eventTarget)
        LOGGER.info(eventTarget.userId)
    }
}
```

## Application(which runs fine, along with working repository)

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.omittedParentName"], exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])
class FrontendApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<FrontendApplication>()
}
```

## Config(which the Test and Application both use)

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.omittedParentName"], useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = [
            ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [Service::class]),
            ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [Component::class]),
            ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [Repository::class]),
            ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [Configuration::class])
        ])
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/core.properties")
class CoreConfig
```

## repository

```java
import EventTarget
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Mapper
@Repository
interface EventTargetRepository {
    fun selectOne(eventTarget: EventTarget): EventTarget
}
```

mapper xml is irrelevant, so it's omitted.

As we can clearly see, the Test and Application literally use the same `@Configuration`. Aside from the fact that making all tests require applicationContext is bad structure, the test should work. Other beans like `@Service` work in the same tests, too.
Any help would be appreciated.
Please refrain from marking as duplicate unless it's a question of `@Autowire` failing only exclusively on `@Repository` for only on `@Test` yet working in release.

Comment: It is not about the annotation. You need to component scan for the implementation for your repository in test context. Where is that?

Comment: @Vaelyr it is in `CoreConfig` I have specified above. ComponentScan scans for the Repository.

Comment: I have discovered that adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [DataSourceAutoConfiguration::class])` to the Test makes it work, yet I have no idea why. I can't wrap my head around this, so any explanations why would be nice.

Comment: Apparently your DataSource has been configured through some other means, as you are excluding it in your main application as well. I would look for the cause related to MyBatis configurations of some sort. Your main application does not have the same context as test. Don't use separate excludes if you want to have identical application context. Have all your excludes/includes in separate configuration files and keep the main file clean to only use imports.

Comment: As it turns out, it was due to a bad config in my externalized datasource config. I should've specified mapper locations there, but it was missing which led to the interface repository being unimplemented. The Application worked due to the autoconfiguration magic(not because of excluding datasourceconfig, but due to the mapper config in autoconfiguration probably) - and the Test didn't have autoconfiguration. Adding proper `@MapperScan` solved the issue, thank you.